# Bootstrap: Responsive navigation bar that fits in every browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, responsive-design

My website has a pretty long navigation bar that shows perfectly on a computer browser. However, when I load the website on a tablet or a smaller browser, the navbar turns in 2 rows.

Like this:
[image]

Now my question is, is it possible to make the navbar smaller or the text so that the navbar shows as it should? Like this:
http://puu.sh/90e1O.png

I've tried to play a bit with the Viewport, but that didn't helped me much :/ Here is a live preview:
http://website.craftshark.net/mcprofile/

You can get the code by the inspector mode. I do have a gist of the Nav here tho, but it could be incomplete: https://gist.github.com/matthijs110/b7c554f0abd4c38fa3c4

Does someone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should work http://www.bootply.com/mjEnd2pAem

I don't recommend using this from line 44-46:

```
<ul class="domain">
    <li><h4 id="domain" title="<?php echo $lang['NAV_IP-TOOLIP'] ?>">play.domain.com</h4></li>
</ul>
```

Because you're wrapping the url with your custom class and the bootstrap menu's css is not affecting this part. You're better off putting it in `a` and add your custom class to the `a` instead of `ul`

EDIT:
Actually, it breaks into 2 line if the resolution is smaller than 993px. Let me see if I can find you another solution

Comment: The only thing I can think of is using 2 navigation menu. A small one for Language and URL, at the same time you can use it as a login menu. You'll probably need that somewhere right?

Answer (score 0):

I thinks problem is that you use custom `padding-left` for div with id=domain, and you wrap `link play.domain.com` by html tag . 
Bootstrap uses css selectors like `.navbar-nav>li>a`. There is no place for `<h4>.` Try to use Bootstrap's navbar as it is without customization indentations (paddings, margins) and everything will be work fine.

Comment: I have to use that padding, otherwise it shows under the language button. And even when I remove the domain section, it still shows as it shows on smaller browsers

Comment: Take a look a the navbar that Bootstrap uses at the top of his site - http://getbootstrap.com/. He has the same structure like yours navbar. Maybe you just copy his code and replace with your conent?

Comment: I've tried that, but when I added my own content, it had the same issue again. I think it just has too much buttons, But i've seen on places that the navbar gets smaller or the font. Would that be possible?

Comment: I think it is because you've got to much buttons in your navbar, i checked and saw that bootstrap also turns in to 2 rows if he has too much buttons